# Code in the InitializeComponent function is deleted

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-controls, initialization

This bug started out of the blue.
I'm changing some controls locations and Visual studio 2010 is re-writing the `InitializeComponent` function.
The problem is that it deleting some of the `new` functions.

Code before:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.advButton1 = new AdvButton();
    this.advButton2 = new AdvButton();
    this.advButton3 = new AdvButton();
    this.advButton4 = new AdvButton();
    this.SuspendLayout();
```

code after moving the button in the designer:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.SuspendLayout();
```

This happens only with my own user control, which are under the same namespace as the form.

Another problem (not consistent):
I'm adding my usercontrol to the form, looking at the `InitializeComponent` function - I don't see the control anywhere.

I've already uninstalled Visual Studio 2010 and re-install it with its Service Pack 1.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it by changing the class `AdvButton` from internal to public.